# WCF Service after changing functionality the wsdl is changed

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

We have an old Homepage which is using our WCF Service. Now we must change some things at the functionality of the service but not the Interface. Only within the service functions! After deploying the new service the Homepage can't get the service functions. I compared the old and new wsdl and there are some changes:

Old wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="DataService"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
    xmlns:i0="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IDataService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:import location="https://<server>/Service.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" namespace="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice"/>
    <wsdl:types/>
    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" type="i0:IDataService">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IDataService_policy"/>
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetSalesPartnerData">
            <soap12:operation style="document" soapAction="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice/IDataService/GetSalesPartnerData"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault">
                <soap12:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault">
                <soap12:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault">
                <soap12:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" type="i0:IDataService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetSalesPartnerData">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice/IDataService/GetSalesPartnerData"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault">
                <soap:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault">
                <soap:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault">
                <soap:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="DataService">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IDataService">
            <soap12:address location="http://<server>/Service.svc/dataservice"/>
            <wsa10:EndpointReference>
                <wsa10:Address>http://<server>/Service.svc/dataservice</wsa10:Address>
            </wsa10:EndpointReference>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IDataService">
            <soap:address location="http://<server>/Service.svc/dataservicebasic"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

New wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="DataService"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
    xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
    xmlns:i0="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IDataService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:TransportBinding
                    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <sp:Layout>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:Strict/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:Layout>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportBinding>
                    <wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
                </wsp:All>
            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
        </wsp:Policy>
        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService_policy">
            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                <wsp:All>
                    <sp:TransportBinding
                        xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TransportToken>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:TransportToken>
                            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:Basic256/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <sp:Layout>+
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:Layout>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportBinding>
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsdl:import location="https://<server>/Service.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" namespace="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice"/>
            <wsdl:types/>
            <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" type="i0:IDataService">
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IDataService_policy"/>
                <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
                <wsdl:operation name="GetSalesPartnerData">
                    <soap12:operation style="document" soapAction="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice/IDataService/GetSalesPartnerData"/>
                    <wsdl:input>
                        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:input>
                    <wsdl:output>
                        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:output>
                    <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault">
                        <soap12:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault" use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:fault>
                    <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault">
                        <soap12:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault" use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:fault>
                    <wsdl:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault">
                        <soap12:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault" use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:fault>
                </wsdl:operation>
            </wsdl:binding>
            <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" type="i0:IDataService">
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpBinding_IDataService_policy"/>
                <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
                <wsdl:operation name="GetSalesPartnerData">
                    <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://service.bizztools.de/services/dataservice/IDataService/GetSalesPartnerData"/>
                    <wsdl:input>
                        <soap:body use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:input>
                    <wsdl:output>
                        <soap:body use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:output>
                    <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault">
                        <soap:fault name="DataServiceDbErrorFault" use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:fault>
                    <wsdl:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault">
                        <soap:fault name="DataServiceFormatErrorFault" use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:fault>
                    <wsdl:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault">
                        <soap:fault name="AuthenticationErrorFault" use="literal"/>
                    </wsdl:fault>
                </wsdl:operation>
            </wsdl:binding>
            <wsdl:service name="DataService">
                <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IDataService">
                    <soap12:address location="https://<server>/Service.svc/dataservice"/>
                    <wsa10:EndpointReference>
                        <wsa10:Address>https://<server>/Service.svc/dataservice</wsa10:Address>
                    </wsa10:EndpointReference>
                </wsdl:port>
                <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IDataService">
                    <soap:address location="https://<server>/Service.svc/dataservicebasic"/>
                </wsdl:port>
            </wsdl:service>
        </wsdl:definitions>
```

It seems that the problem is the wsp:policy. Why has the new wsdl this policy and the old one not? How can I change the wsdl. Unfotunately we can't change the Homepage!

I using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for creating the WCF Service.

Comment: How did you create the legacy WSDL? using what versions of VS, .NET Framework and SvcUtil.exe?

Comment: I got the wsdl from the service with the browser https://<server>/Service.svc?wsdl. VS 2010 and .Net Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. It wasn't the different wsdl. It was a problem with the AddressFiltering at the IIS. I got the error message: **The message with To `'http://<service>'` cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree'**. So I fixed the Problem with the Attribute `[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]` on the service class.